# Is there a way to install the full versions of Thunderbird and LibreOffice, using Snaps?

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, snap, thunderbird

My dad is on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. He wants to install the latest versions of both Thunderbird and LibreOffice (as some of his files aren't compatible with the versions that came with the ISO). I've suggested he download the Snap versions but he says that it only installs the 'lite' versions.

What's the best way for him to completely purge both apps on the system and install the latest 'full' versions of both applications? Everything I've suggested to him, thus far, hasn't worked.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If the problem is "files aren't compatible," then ask about that and provide some details. Maybe a newer version fixes the problem., but maybe not. Not sure what he means by a "lite" version of LibreOffice. The current version of LO Snap is 6.4.5, same as in the 20.04 (-updates) repository. Ubuntu 20.10, currently in pre-release has 7.0.1rc1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to purge LibreOffice :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then goto https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/ and download the version 6.4.6 (my suggestion). Once it is downloaded he can right-click on the file and install click on `Open with Software Install`

For Thunderbird, you can uninstall it in the Software Center, see [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/uninstall-thunderbird)

Then follow [this link](https://www.debugpoint.com/2020/07/email-client-thunderbird-78-is-here-with-major-changes/) to install Thunderbird 78

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to remove any existing Thunderbird and LibreOffice.

```
sudo apt remove thunderbird
sudo apt remove libreoffice
```

Then, it's really easy from there. This presumes you have snapd already installed and haven't removed it - as it's installed by default on 20.04.

```
sudo snap install thunderbird
sudo snap install libreoffice
```

If you've previously removed snapd, it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, this isn't necessarily the best fix. The problem you have is that files are incompatible. The solution could be all sorts of things and updating/changing these two applications won't necessarily solve those problems. However, that is the question you asked and this is the answer to that question.

[LibreOffice](https://snapcraft.io/install/libreoffice/ubuntu)
[Thunderbird](https://snapcraft.io/install/thunderbird/ubuntu)